# Groovy: Timeout due to proxy not being set (java.net.ConnectException)

Tags: groovy, proxy

I want to use a Groovy script to access a webpage. However I'm behind a proxy.

Here's a test script that fails...

```
println "Google page is..."
println 'http://www.google.com'.toURL().text
```

Here's the output...

```
>groovy proxytester.groovy 
Google page is... 
Caught: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
   at checker.run(proxytester.groovy:2)
```

**How do I set proxy server information in Groovy?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Or, from inside Groovy itself:

```
System.properties << [ 'http.proxyHost':'proxyHost', 'http.proxyPort':'port' ]
```

Answer (score 3):

The proxy information can be set for the JVM by passing arguments on the groovy command line, eg...

> groovy -**Dhttp.proxyHost**=*proxyHost* -**Dhttp.proxyPort**=*Port Number* proxytester.groovy

This script then works...

```
println "Google page is..."
println 'http://www.google.com'.toURL().text
```

Here's the results...

```
Google page is
<!doctype html><html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage"><head><meta
http-equiv="content-type.....
```

See the [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html) for further information